# Get Groups From OU using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'd like to use AccountManagement to list all the groups in an Organizational Unit.

The following snippet works with DirectoryServices but I would have to instanciate GroupPrincipal with the DirectoryEntry path in the result (which feels like a dirty fix).

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Marketing,OU=Operations,OU=Applications,DC=mycompany,DC=local")
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(root);
        ds.Filter = "(objectCategory=group)";
        SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();
```

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set the `PrincipalContext` to the OU where you want to start the search and use the `PrincipalSearcher`-class in `System.DirectoryService.AccountManagement` to accomplish what you need, like this:

```
PrincipalContext yourOU = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mycompany.local", "OU=Marketing,OU=Operations,OU=Applications,DC=mycompany,DC=local");
GroupPrincipal findAllGroups = new GroupPrincipal(yourOU, "*");
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(findAllGroups);
foreach(var group in ps.FindAll())
{
  Console.WriteLine(group.DistinguishedName);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had tried that but missed the wildcard "*".